# Allow the user to execute algorithms "step by step" in Java

Tags: java

I am developing a support software for teaching graph (algorithms, as Travelling Salesman Problem, Graph Coloring, etc ...) and I would allow **the user** to execute the algorithms "step by step", so that the user can control the execution of the algorithms and have time to observe the changes.

I would like suggestions on how to implement "step by step execution" in Java...
If there is library or if anyone has implemented something similar and could share the code.

Thanks :)

---

They will not have acces to de code or IDE, They will be front users of my program

The User interface is like this, where will be added buttons to next step, pause, etc:

[image]

Comment: Could they not just use an interactive debugger? All modern IDEs have pretty sophisticated ways of stepping through code.

Comment: They will not have acces to de code or IDE, They will be front users of my program.

Comment: Then basically, you're building a program similar to an interactive  debugger.

Comment: In your non-IDE user interface, have you considered including buttons to run, pause and step?

Comment: Wait! You are developing a teaching software for programmers and you don't even know how to write it? :D That is soooo wierd! Just put some while`s as breakpoints waiting for some conditions like keypress or something...

Comment: @Andy Thomas,  off course :)

Comment: You will also need to consider how the algorithms are implemented. Will they be written in actual java code, or are they an interpreted series of instructions stored in a data structure? How will the algorithm be presented to the user? What about the data that the algorithms store/manipulate?

Comment: @Sizik, Implemented in Java only, My program will help the user to understand the functioning of the algorithms, and based on this understanding they will need create your own solution... The algorithm will not be presented to the users.

Comment: @FlashThunder The "step by step execution" is a very small part of the entire software. I don't want to fill all my code of "if", my algorithms are ready, I imagine that there is a much better solution, is what I'm searching.

Comment: I am afraid you're going to need some abstractions to represent loops, procedure calls and possibly recursion. This way you can also add support for step by step execution of each of those. Then you can encode the algorithms using these abstraction and the user can see the step by step execution. I'm saying this because I doubt you'll be able to actually execute code step by step in a production application (besides being potentially dangerous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option *might* be to use the [Java Debug Interface (JDI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html). Oracle provides [these examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/examples.html).

However, that's not what I would do. One step on invisible Java source code might not correspond to a visual change. (In addition, I haven't yet used JDI, and don't know how complex it would be.)

I would consider presenting pseudocode to the user. Internally, I would hold a parallel **[abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree),** such that each node represents (and can execute) one step. One pseudocode algorithm step might correspond to more than one Java statement. (You don't have to write a parser, if you write the pseudocode and AST in parallel.)

You'll need a class to walk the tree, executing nodes. Maintain a state of execution, including states for running, stepping or paused. The walker needs to watch the state and behave accordingly.

The walker needs to run in a worker thread, so that those UI buttons to run, step and pause can be pressed during execution of the algorithm.

Comment: I was even seeing these two options, but I was in doubt whether JDI would serve the purpose and I was not understanding how an AST would be used ... Your explanations helped a lot. I will continue to research a little more ... :)

Comment: You're welcome. I did something similar years ago with the Knuth-Morris-Pratt string-matching algorithm. Good luck with yours.